# Python list comprehension filtering out files in directory

Tags: python, database, file, automation, directory

```
#To pull content from dirNames directory
dirNames = str(glob.glob('.\\Output'+ globalData.__TWO_BACK_SLASH_SEPERATORS__ + globalData.__MANUAL_STRING_OUTPUT__ + globalData.__TWO_BACK_SLASH_SEPERATORS__ +'*'))
print ("Dir Names:: "+dirNames)

#Seperate the contents of dirNames into list dirNames[0], dirNames[1]....etc
dirNames = [dir for dir in dirNames if os.path.isdir( dir)]
print("\nPost Filetring Dir names are ::{}".format(dirNames))
```

> > Output: Dir Names:: ['.\Output\ManualOutput\152_156_92_230_NLA_6_0_0_08112022',
> > '.\Output\ManualOutput\152_156_92_230_NLA_6_0_0_112022_1_REV01',
> > '.\Output\ManualOutput\152_156_92_230_NLA_6_0_0_21112022_1_REV01']
>
> Post Filetring Dir names are ::['.', '\', '\', '\', '\', '\',
> '\', '.', '\', '\', '\', '\', '\', '\', '.', '\', '\', '\',
> '\', '\', '\']

The output after filtering is incomplete as only the back slashes have been parsed. This code works fine in another module where the Directory is only .\Output\152_156_92_230_NLA_6_0_0_112022_1_REV01, but with this directory format .\Output\ManualOutput\152_156_92_230_NLA_6_0_0_112022_1_REV01 I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're passing a list of strings to `os.path.isdir`, which isn't what it expects. Either pass it each directory name individually, or split on the newlines.

```
dirNames = [dir for dir in dirNames.split('\n') if os.path.isdir( dir)]
```

Comment: Good shout, but curious as to why it works in my other module, everything is the same with the addition of one subdirectory so... .\\Output\\[File name] works fine, but in this one \\Output\\ManualOutput\\[filename] is facing issues. any ideas?